# Appending multiple Excel sheets in a dataset

Tags: foreach, append, stata, stata-macros

**ORIGINAL QUESTION**

While importing a large dataset in work, I noticed some unexpected behaviour where Stata appears to "forget" a local macro, when using the `append` command.

This seems all the more strange as it appears to be a phenomenon specific to this one command (I tested with `save` and the code worked as expected).

```
*****************
** SET UP
******************
local datasets "auto.dta auto2.dta"
global data "/Users/Seansmac/Desktop/stata_question"
save "$data/test_data.dta", replace emptyok
local datasets "auto.dta auto2.dta"


** Save Stata data in two Excel sheets. This replicates the status of my raw data at work.
foreach dataset in `datasets'{


    di "`dataset' loaded"
     sysuse `dataset', clear
     gen data_name = "`dataset'"
     tab data_name
     export excel using "$data/auto_excel.xlsx", sheet("`dataset'") first(variables) sheetreplace
     di "`dataset' saved in excel"
     } 

*****************
** Demo of Problem
******************

import excel "$data/auto_excel.xlsx", desc

local worksheets `r(N_worksheet)'
di `worksheets'

  forvalues i = 1/`worksheets' { 
    di " Sheet number  `i'"


     local shtname`i' `r(worksheet_`i')'
     di "loading database: `shtname`i''"

     import excel "$data/auto_excel.xlsx", sheet("`shtname`i''")  clear firstrow

          di "database: `shtname`i'' loaded"

      append using "$data/test_data.dta", force

      di "database: `shtname`i'' appended"        
}


***** Show only the same data  was appended twice
     use "$data/test_data.dta", clear
     tab data_name

** I include this tab to demonstrate that only one of the two data sets is appended. 

*****************
** END
*****************
```

Apologies if the example is a little cluttered but I often find it helpful to use `display` when working with locals. To run the code, all that is required is that you change the global data.

To maintain fidelity with my problem in work I include the `import excel` section; I don't understand the problem sufficiently to make the example any more minimal.

**ORIGINAL QUESTION EDITED**

Below are two code chunks. The first demonstrates that the `append` command appears to work as I would expect it to (I note that I had forgot to use `save` in my original question). This chunk demonstrates that although appending a dataset with an empty dataset may not be entirely intuitive, it still works fine. The advantage of this method is that it eliminates the need for a conditional statement when loading files.

In the second code chunk, I try to use the `append` command in the same basic way, but this time in a loop. This code chunk is copy and pasted from Pearly Spencer with three minor changes:

1. I save an empty dataset at the beginning
2. I comment-out the logical `if` statements
3. I `append` with the empty dataset instead (and then `save` it, so the second time round it shouldn't be empty).

The local macro which Stata "forgets" is `shtname`. If you examine the `display` statements, **nothing is printed after the first loop. This is the location of my question.** To further demonstrate this, the `tab` command at the end of the script shows that the variable `data_name` has 148 observations of `auto.dta` and none of `auto2.dta`. This shows the same (ie the first) data set was appended twice. This suggests (to me) that the `append` part of the script works fine, but there is a problem with the local marco, `shtname`.

*** DEMONSTRATE APPEND APPEARS TO WORK ***

```
clear all
cd "[**INSERT CD**]"

*Create empty data set to append later
save "test_data_noloop.dta", replace emptyok

* load first dataset
sysuse auto.dta, clear
* Gen a variable indicating what dataset it is
gen dataset = "auto_1"
* append data with empty dataset
append using "test_data_noloop.dta"
save "test_data_noloop.dta", replace

clear
*load second dataset
sysuse auto2.dta, clear
* gen dataset variable again
gen dataset = "auto_2"
* append with the previously saved dataset
append using "test_data_noloop.dta"

* Demonstrate both datasets have been appended
tab dataset
```

*** FOLLOW PEARLY SPENCER, WITH SMALL ADJUSTMENTS ***

```
clear all
cd "[**INSERT CD**]"


local datasets "auto.dta auto2.dta"

** Added the following line
save "test_data.dta", replace emptyok 

foreach dataset in `datasets'{
    display "`dataset' loaded"
    sysuse `dataset', clear
    generate data_name = "`dataset'"
    tab data_name
    export excel using "auto_excel.xlsx", sheet("`dataset'") first(variables) sheetreplace
    display "`dataset' saved in excel"
} 


import excel "auto_excel.xlsx", desc

local worksheets `r(N_worksheet)'
display `worksheets'

forvalues i = 1 / `worksheets' { 
    display " Sheet number  `i'"
    local shtname`i' `r(worksheet_`i')'
    display "loading database: `shtname`i''"
    import excel "auto_excel.xlsx", sheet("`shtname`i''")  clear firstrow
    *if `i' == 1 save "test_data.dta", replace
    display "database: `shtname`i'' loaded"
    *if `i' > 1 {
        append using "test_data.dta", force
        save "test_data.dta", replace
    *}
    display "database: `shtname`i'' appended"        
}


use "test_data.dta", clear
tab data_name
```

To address some remarks in the comments, auto2.dta can be found when typing `sysuse dir` into the console. It is thus a dataset available to all. I have tried my best to keep my code replicable, and unless I am mistaken all that needs to be done is to set the `cd` for the above code to work.

Secondly, I have tried hard to ensure I haven't made a stupid logical error (as mentioned above, I realise I omitted saving my file in my original question, which would indeed mean I am appending an empty dataset each time). That said, it may be a case that I've looked at this problem for so long I can no longer see the wood from the trees; so please go easy if it's still a one liner type issue!

Finally, I never said Stata is forgetting the local macro, merely that it *appears* to do so. Hence I ask the question to understand what is going on (or, more likely, where I've made the mistake).

***SCREEN SHOT OF MY OUTPUT***
See red marks where locals are not being displayed.[image]

***EDIT #3
This image appears to show the (as yet) unexplained behaviour stems from `append` and not `import`.

[image]

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Append sheet 2 in a Stata dataset that already has sheet 1? It looks that you are using append in the wrong way

Comment: Sorry @NickCox! Slip of the tongue. I was too focused on ensuring I wrote Stata rather than STATA...

Comment: @SeánMcK you are not doing anything different from what i proposed. Appending an empty dataset in the first iteration of the loop does not make sense. The fact remains that there is a logical error in your thinking. In addition, your local macro question does not make any sense whatsoever either. Which macro does Stata (appear) to forget? You have yet to tell us.

Comment: @PearlySpencer, apologies if I haven't been clear. I have made additional edits, which I hope will clarify my issue. In the first code chunk I show why appending an empty dataset can work (even if it is perhaps not the most intuitive method, though for me it is tidier). For the second part, as I showed in my edit this morning, I removed the IF statements in your code. So it is different from what you propose. Finally, I have specifically clarified where my problem is. When you run my code it should be clear from glancing at the display statements.

Comment: All local macros are being displayed fine on my computer. And just because something 'works' does not mean it is logically correct or good programming practice.

Comment: Hi, please see screen shot. I don't understand why this is different for you. (Also, I never said I was unwilling to learn better programming practice)

Comment: We keep having the same conversation man. See the output in my answer to see that when following the logical approach everything works as intended. Your approach is a hack.

Comment: Look I understand that you dislike my approach and find it illogical and stupid etc. You seem much more experienced than me, so I'm happy to acquiesce to your knowledge. However, there remains the fundamental issue that motivated my question all along. Now you say my approach is a hack, fine. But aside from that fact that you don't like my appending an empty dataset, you haven't told me why the local variable does not appear the second time round. This is not obvious to me and would be very helpful to learn WHY my approach is wrong/illogical.

Comment: If after all this discussion you still cannot see why your approach is illogical, this has nothing to do with me. The point of my previous comment was that hacks have unintended consequences. Chances are that the way you use `append` conflicts with the loop. With that said, I think i will call it a day and focus on helping others who find my answers helpful.

Comment: @SeánMcK  issue `return list` to see what r-class results remain in memory before you copy them to locals.

Comment: Are you executing the script all at once? Local definitions won't be visible if a script is executed in chunks from a do-file editor window.

Comment: Thanks Nick. Yes, i'm aware locals don't carry over if the script isn't executed all at once. So yes, I execute it all together. Regarding return list, this is helpful in that it demonstrates my problem more clearly (put one before and after the append statement and it shows that locals disappear), but unfortunately i'm still in the dark as to why this happens. This seems to me to be a legitimate question, even if my approach is not the best from a best practice POV.

Comment: @PearlySpencer, I appreciate your help, but I simply wanted to know why Stata has this behaviour. Clearly I can't see why my approach is illogical and you have refused to show me exactly why, it is. To me this seems like a reasonable question.

Comment: Yes, @Pearly's guess is my guess too.

Comment: Hi @PearlySpencer, appreciate the help -sincerely. This problem seemed to produce strange behaviour and despite my flawed approach this seemed worth understanding. You clearly disagree. I appreciate your efforts nonetheless. That said, I stand by my right to ask.

Comment: Please see my latest screenshot. I'm not sure if it's entirely clear (that's the biggest screen shot I can manage), but the issue does seem to stem from append, and not import.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that you want to append successive Excel sheets into one Stata dataset.

Below is a working version of your toy example.

Set up:

```
clear all
local datasets "auto.dta auto2.dta"
```

Save Stata data in two excel sheets:

```
foreach dataset in `datasets'{
    display "`dataset' loaded"
    sysuse `dataset', clear
    generate data_name = "`dataset'"
    tab data_name
    export excel using "auto_excel.xlsx", sheet("`dataset'") first(variables) sheetreplace
    display "`dataset' saved in excel"
}
```

Demonstrate the solution to the problem:

```
import excel "auto_excel.xlsx", desc

local worksheets `r(N_worksheet)'
display `worksheets'

forvalues i = 1 / `worksheets' { 
    display " Sheet number  `i'"
    local shtname`i' `r(worksheet_`i')'
    display "loading database: `shtname`i''"
    import excel "auto_excel.xlsx", sheet("`shtname`i''")  clear firstrow
    if `i' == 1 save "test_data.dta", replace
    display "database: `shtname`i'' loaded"
    if `i' > 1 {
        append using "test_data.dta", force
        save "test_data.dta", replace
    }
    display "database: `shtname`i'' appended"        
}
```

Show the results:

```
use "test_data.dta", clear
tab data_name
```

(I broke the code in different snippets for better legibility.)

---

**EDIT:**

Stata can `use` **only one** dataset at a time. The way the `append` command works is by 'attaching' the data from the specified external dataset to those already loaded into memory (i.e `use`d). The reason the version of your example is not giving you the desired outcome is because you are trying to append an empty dataset every time after you import an Excel sheet. This is an error in logic.

---

**EDIT 2:**

The output generated:

```
. clear all

. local datasets "auto.dta auto2.dta"

. 
. foreach dataset in `datasets'{
  2.     display "`dataset' loaded"
  3.     sysuse `dataset', clear
  4.     generate data_name = "`dataset'"
  5.     tab data_name
  6.     export excel using "auto_excel.xlsx", sheet("`dataset'") first(variables) sheetreplace
  7.     display "`dataset' saved in excel"
  8. } 
auto.dta loaded
(1978 Automobile Data)

  data_name |      Freq.     Percent        Cum.
------------+-----------------------------------
   auto.dta |         74      100.00      100.00
------------+-----------------------------------
      Total |         74      100.00
file auto_excel.xlsx saved
auto.dta saved in excel
auto2.dta loaded
(1978 Automobile Data)

  data_name |      Freq.     Percent        Cum.
------------+-----------------------------------
  auto2.dta |         74      100.00      100.00
------------+-----------------------------------
      Total |         74      100.00
file auto_excel.xlsx saved
auto2.dta saved in excel

. 
. import excel "auto_excel.xlsx", desc

      Sheet | Range
  ----------+----------
   auto.dta | A1:M75
  auto2.dta | A1:M75

. 
. local worksheets `r(N_worksheet)'

. display `worksheets'
2

. 
. forvalues i = 1 / `worksheets' { 
  2.     display " Sheet number  `i'"
  3.     local shtname`i' `r(worksheet_`i')'
  4.     display "loading database: `shtname`i''"
  5.     import excel "auto_excel.xlsx", sheet("`shtname`i''")  clear firstrow
  6.     if `i' == 1 save "test_data.dta", replace
  7.     display "database: `shtname`i'' loaded"
  8.     if `i' > 1 {
  9.         append using "test_data.dta", force
 10.         save "test_data.dta", replace
 11.     }
 12.     display "database: `shtname`i'' appended"        
 13. }
 Sheet number  1
loading database: auto.dta
file test_data.dta saved
database: auto.dta loaded
database: auto.dta appended
 Sheet number  2
loading database: auto2.dta
database: auto2.dta loaded
(note: variable rep78 was byte in the using data, but will be str9 now)
file test_data.dta saved
database: auto2.dta appended

. 
. use "test_data.dta", clear

. tab data_name

  data_name |      Freq.     Percent        Cum.
------------+-----------------------------------
   auto.dta |         74       50.00       50.00
  auto2.dta |         74       50.00      100.00
------------+-----------------------------------
      Total |        148      100.00

. 
end of do-file
```

Comment: Hi Pearly, I appreciate you getting back to me, but I think it would be helpful if you elaborated on how/why I use append incorrectly. In particular, your working version uses a different technique. Rather than appending to an empty data set, you use a logical statement to save and then append both datasets. This of course is entirely valid, but I specifically wanted to import and append in the manner I have shown in my example. If this is bad practice in Stata, then I'm happy to be corrected. Secondly, it's still not clear why Stata forgets the local marco, which is the core of my question.

Comment: @SeánMcK Stata does not forget anything. And your question is not really about a local macro; it is about how to properly `append` files. In your toy example, you are repeatedly trying to append an empty file. This is an error in logic. If you follow your code carefully you should see this. What you are trying to do is logically flawed.